# how can i get the source code path && file names from an ELF file(compired with -g)?

Tags: linux, elf

I want to get the source code path && source names just through the ELF file, the **.debug_str** section contains what i need, but how can i filter them out?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to use this command and tools like sed or grep.

```
$ readelf --string-dump=.debug_str YOUR_PROGRAM
```

this show path and source file name:

```
$ readelf --string-dump=.debug_str YOUR_PROGRAM | sed -n '/\/\|\.c/{s/.*\]  //p}'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ readelf --string-dump=.debug_str YOUR_PROGRAM
```

works fine.

However, make sure your_program is not stripped by using command

```
file YOUR_PROGRAM
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way:

```
readelf --syms YOUR-PROGGRAM |tee /tmp/log

vim /tmp/log
:vim "FILE" %
```

You will get all file names, however without path.

Answer (score 1):

`readelf` holds the key, but you don't want to dump strings willy-nilly. Use the `-wi` option to properly format the info.
For example, create a shell script thus:

```
readelf -wi $1 | grep -B1 DW_AT_comp_dir | \
    awk '/DW_AT_name/{name = $NF; getline; print $NF"/"name}'
```

which further summarizes the output of `readelf -wi`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `readelf` and `objdump` requires some awkward post-processing and, in some cases, knowledge of how the symbol file is built. (For example, the ELF section isn't necessarily named ".debug_str".)

An alternative approach is to let GDB do the heavy lifting for you:

```
gdb --nx -q -ex 'file xxx.out' -ex 'info sources' -ex 'quit'
```

The `--nx` option disables processing of the gdbinit files.

The `-q` (quiet) option removes the version preamble output when gdb starts.

This results in proper file paths and is generally much more useful.

The output will need to be post-processed to select just the lines with source files, strip the commas, and concatenate them.

If you're writing a bash script, you can use:

```
symbol_file="$1"
source_files=$(gdb --nx -q -ex "file ${symbol_file}" -ex 'info sources' -ex 'quit' | grep -v 'Source files for which' | tr -d '[\n,]')
```

There are a couple of caveats:

- Depending on the build environment and tool chain for the program, the file paths may need adjusting. Refer to GDB's `set substitute-path` command; you may want to insert some rules by adding more `-ex` commands.
- The `info sources` command applies any path substitution rules that may be applied. This can be beneficial if the program was built from a source tree in a different location from your source.