# header files from an ELF file

Tags: header, elf

I managed to extract source files from a debug section of an ELF by using objdump. However it doesn't look easy to extract paths of header files. If I try to disassemble to get those, it takes long time as big as the ELF file is.
What could be the fast way to get header files? 
Please give me your brilliant idea

Comment: "I managed to extract source files" -- no, you didn't (it's impossible). You probably did *something else*. Anyway, your question is exceedingly unclear.

Comment: look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31333337/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-path-file-names-from-an-elf-filecompired-with. But it just shows paths of source files.